# Unknown error: <class 'apt_Error'> package needs to be reinstalled but cant find an archive for it

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, printing, scanner

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10, after which I discovered I cannot connect or print using my Brother MFC-L2703DW printer/scanner, nor can I scan. I tried downloading and installing from the Brother site the "Driver install tool" for Linux debian, but I just get this message back "Unknown error: class apt error - "Package mfcl2700dwlpr:i386 needs to be reinstalled but I cant find an archive for it".

I tried rebooting and checked "Software and updates" and under Ubuntu software all the boxes are checked.

Comment: From the packagename `mfcl2700dwlpr:i386` it looks like it's from a Brother printer specific PPA. Also, blindly executing "the "Driver install tool" for Linux debian," is unlikely to succeed on Ubuntu. You'll have to read the  "Driver install tool"  and figure it out.

Comment: Going through the driver install tool (which was from the brother website for this printer/scanner model), it comes back with "usb://dev/usblp@ -E. lpadmin: unable to connect to server: Bad file descriptor". Tried to specify printer ip address and again I get "bad file descriptor - unable to connect to server".